# Cocoapods + Cannot load underlying module for 'x'

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, cocoapods, alamofire

I am running XCode 7, Swift 2.0, iOS 9.

I want to install Alamofire in my project using Cocoapods. I have done the following:

`gem install cocoapods`

`pod setup`

`pod init`

Updated Podfile to:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'JSONeg' do

  pod 'Alamofire', :branch => 'swift-2'

end
```

Then I installed the pod:

`pod install`

And I added the following to ViewController.swift

`import Alamofire`

This raises the following error:

`Cannot load underlying module for 'Alamofire'`

I tested with another pod and it raised the same error, so I guess the problem is with the installation of Cocoapods. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check you have imported the needed frameworks

Answer (score 216):

This seems to be a bug in XCode. I had the same problem, and as described in the comments of another answer to this question, building the project made the error go away.

Comment: I almost come here at the start of any project... Thanks buddy

Comment: Damn workaround still works.. XCode should be open sourced.

Answer (score 25):

Go to Product > Build and it will resolve the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me:

1. Close your project
2. In terminal go to your project directory
3. Add this command: pod update
4. After that all your pods will be updated. Just run your project

Answer (score 9):

**Cannot load underlying module for 'x'for SWIFT :**

***How to fix the Issue:***

***step:1*** Create a New project and build&run Successfully without installing pod.

***step:2*** After build&run the Project Successfully ,Now try to install pod and then try to **importrealm,alamofire,charts etc** it will work like a charm.

**Failure Case** --> New project -> Add (realm,alamofire,charts etc) via cocoapods w/o building first -> open Xcode workspace -> build&run

**Success Case** -->New project -> build&run -> add (realm,alamofire,charts etc)via cocoapods -> open Xcode workspace -> build&run again = success

Comment: You cannot consider to "start a new project" every time you see this error when 99% of the time it is happening in an existing project. What about just trying 'pod update'

Answer (score 9):

Once you have installed Alamofire pod.

Step.1 you should open your project by double click on your_project_name.xcworkspace file.

Step.2 Go to project settings --> Build Phases --> Link Binary with Libraries --> Add framework "Alamofire.framework"

Thats it!!

Now you can import the module

Answer (score 8):

I tried all of these solutions: Re-building, Cleaning, Re-installing the pods, etc., but In my case, it was a problem of changing my 'Build Active Architecture Only' setting to 'No', due to an AR library I was using. Changed it back to 'Yes' and it was fixed. Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: True, that was the main problem,you have to clean with command-shift-K

Comment: I had to set it from YES to NO. Weird.

Answer (score 8):

What has helped in my case:

1) Close the project and XCode

2) In the terminal repeat command

```
> pod install
```

3) Open the project

(If it does not help, try to remove Pod/ folder before reinstalling)

Comment: Also, remove `Pod/` folder before reinstalling

Answer (score 8):

I had to do a Product > (Opt Click) Clean Build Folder ... then ran again and the issue was gone.

Answer (score 5):

I am on Xcode Version 8.3.1 (8E1000a). Somehow this problem occurs when I wanted to pod install SwiftCloudant module. Probably I did not close my Xcode when I run pod install.

I fixed this manually adding the SwiftCloudant.framework in the Targets > General tab.

[Targets > General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSjUP.png)

Comment: After everything else failed, this actually worked.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Im my case it was a different reason, it was the **Other swift flags** in my targets build setting, i had to add inherited flag to the top.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible scenario: make sure the test target is defined within the scope of the parent target (not outside of it)

e.g.

```
target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.1'

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'OCMock', '~> 2.0.1'
  end
end
```

If instead it looks like:

```
target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.1'
end

target 'MyAppTests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  pod 'OCMock', '~> 2.0.1'
end
```

then you'll also receive this error.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked if you have a recent version of Cocoapods ? You can update by either updating all your gems :

```
sudo gem update
```

or just reinstall Cocoapods:

```
 [sudo] gem install cocoapods
```

If that doesn't help take also a look at : [CocoaPods - build for iOS 9 / Swift 2 with Xcode-beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804866/cocoapods-build-for-ios-9-swift-2-with-xcode-beta)

where is shows you how to easily change the Command-Line tools version in the Xcode Preferences "Locations" tab, and change "Command Line Tools" to Xcode 7.0.

Comment: Yes it was the most recent build. I just figured out the problem though. I built the project, and all of a sudden, it worked.

Comment: Ok then please answer your own question with the solution you figured out so that others can fix that problem when they encounter that,

Answer (score 3):

Follow the steps:

1.Install pods
2.Open workSpace
3.Run/build your application
4.Then you can import the framework

Answer (score 2):

Same issue for me.
I solved that by removing Alamofire version in pod file.

**Pod file as**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, "8.0"

# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'GettingSwift' do
 pod 'Alamofire'
end

target 'GettingSwiftTests' do
end
```

Comment: for me it was the missing `use_frameworks`

Answer (score 2):

#### Could not load underlying module

1. Check framework path: `Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths`.
2. Make sure the path to a framework contains no space.
3. If the path contains a variable, find the value of the variables by searching the variable name in your `Build Settings`.
4. Make sure the value of the variables contains no space.
5. If the path contains spaces, rename those directories that contain spaces.
6. Clean and build the project.

In summary, make sure your `<Project Root>` path contains no space. Otherwise, rename the `dir` that contains spaces, then clean and build your project.

e.g. If this is your project root: `/Users/handsomeboy/ios app/Fancy App/`, rename the folder that has spaces. One way to get rid of the space: change `'ios app'` to `'ios_app'`

Answer (score 2):

Setting `GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN` (displayed as "Symbols Hidden by Default" in target settings) to `YES` in framework being linked helped me to get rid of this error. I've spent 2 days to find this out, hope it will help someone :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case:

1. Comment line of `//import Pod_Module`

2. Go to Project -> Clean or use shortcut key (Command+Shift+K)

2. Close your project

3. In terminal go to your project directory

4. run `> pod install`

5. open `.xcworkspace` file and build it!

6. Uncomment line of `import Pod_Module`

Answer (score 2):

At this URL: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/441

One of the users wrote this:

Clean did not work, re-installing from pods did not work, installing from carthage did not work, manual install did not work. I finally got it to work after Build for Testing.

So i tried this (xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b)):

[image]

It did work for me. Error gone now.

Note: My pod was not Alamofire so i guess it will work for every Pod.

Answer (score 0):

When installing CocoaPods, be sure to specify ios 9.0 by deleteing the #. Therefore, `# platform :ios, '9.0'` should just be `platform :ios, '9.0'` Then, if the error shows again, simply build and run. After you build and run, the error should not return.

Also, this can occur if you have more than one version of Xcode installed on your computer. Quit (not just close) all versions of Xcode first.

Answer (score 0):

try Build For testing works for me

Answer (score 0):

If you have verified that your Pods have been successfully installed, then the error may be associated with your derived data remaining from before you installed the Pods. You can clear your derived data by going to `File -> Workspace Settings... -> Derived Data`. Deleting the derived data folder associated with your app and cleaning your build should solve the problem.